# If someone doesn't show his/her friends in Facebook, will that person appear in another friend's list?

Tags: facebook, friends, friend-list

If someone doesn't show his/her friends in Facebook, would that person appear in another friend's list?

I mean, I want to hide my friend list. I don't want to be related in terms of Facebook friendship with anyone.

If I hide the list, would I appear in my friend's friend list when a stranger looks at it?

I am referring to hiding the list from strangers (people who aren't my friends on Facebook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will be visible on your friends-friend list. AFAIK there is no way to disable this unless your friend too hides his/her friends list.